# Toolbar Menu Item appears without margin/padding

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-menu

The menu items are rendered without any margin/padding.

[image]

How can I center the Menu item in the toolbar. I am using the theme Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar.

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ParkingOffendersActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

activity_parking_offenders.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parking_offenders_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ParkingOffendersActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/parking_offenders_toolbar"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: On your toolbar remove `minHeight` bc it's broken (or doesn't work as one would expect AKA as you can see icons respect it but text and actual toolbar size don't) and set `android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"`. This will ensure your toolbar will be 56dp tall in phone portrait, 48dp in phone landscape and 64dp on tablets.

Comment: thanks, fixed the problem.